# Animating constraints for iOS xibs

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, interface-builder, xib

I have been reading a few posts about animating when working with xibs in iOS development. Mostly what I read was to not animate the frame but instead animate the constraints. I have constrained a label to be in the centre of the view on start up, then I animate it up and present a login textfield (The typical login stuff you see).

[image]

I did this animating the frame and of course when I click on the the text field, the view applies the original constraint to the "My Title" label and pushes it back to its original centre location.

[image]

How can I remove the centring constraint and add a new constraint to in-force a space from the top programmatically?

Here is my animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8
                      delay: 1.0
     usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8
      initialSpringVelocity: 0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations: ^{
                     self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(self.titleLabel.frame, 0, -self.view.frame.size.height/4.5);
                 } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished)
                     {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8
                                               delay: 0.3
                              usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8
                               initialSpringVelocity: 0.5
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations: ^{

                                              self.userIdTextField.alpha = 1.0;
                                              self.userPasswordTextField.alpha = 1.0;
                                              self.loginButton.alpha = 1.0;

                                          } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                                          }];
                     }
                 }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is way easier than you would think it would be.  You can create IBOutlets for constraints and change their constant values instead of removing and re-adding.

From your Storyboard, control-drag your constraint into the source code of your view controller.  This will give you the option to create an IBOutlet pointing to the constraint.

Then all you have to do in your UIView animation is change the value of your constraints *constant* property.

Here is an example of an Auto-layout constraint outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myViewHeight;
```

Here is an example of animation code that change the height of a view by changing the constraint constant:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                  delay: 0.0
                options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
             animations:^{
                     _myViewHeight.constant += 20.0f;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
            completion:nil];
```

This may not be exactly what you want to do but you should be able to modify your constraints in this manner to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Had to structure my constrains different. Instead of centre constraining I constrained it a distance from the centre Y, made an IBOutlet to that constraint, then animated that.